# Memcache in node.js is returning object with varying size

Tags: node.js, binary, memcached

Long-time reader, first-time poster.

I am using node v0.6.6 on OS X 10.7. I have not yet tried this in any other environment. I am using this client: https://github.com/elbart/node-memcache

When I use the following code, `data` randomly contains a few more bytes (as reported by `console.log()`), which leads to this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzOsw.jpg (and many other JPG do this). favicon seems OK and HTML/CSS/javascript all work.

In other words: if I request the image, ~70% of the time the image is returned correctly; the other 30% - `data` reports a few more bytes and the image appears corrupt in the browser.

```
client.get(key, function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': type, 'Content-Length': data.length});
        console.log('Sending with length: ' + data.length);
        res.end(data, 'binary');
    }
});
```

I have been messing with this for several hours and I can honestly say I am stumped. I am hoping someone can show me the error in my ways. I tried searching if there was a way to properly store binary data with memcache but there's no relevant information.

Extra information: it happens with various JPG images; all images are around 100-300KB or less in filesize. For example, one image has reported the following sizes: 286442, 286443, 286441. This problem DOES NOT occur if I straight read data from disk and serve it with node.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** I updated my node version and issue persists. Actual test source photo and corrupt photo can be found in my comment below (stackoverflow doesn't permit more links).

Comment: can you link to the uncorrupted version of the same picture for reference? Also, try upgrading your version of node, sounds like it could be a bug in how node handles buffers?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated my node version and issue persists. Actual test source photo: http://imgur.com/XUTf2 ; actual test corrupt photo: http://imgur.com/NuaK4

Comment: I ran `vbindiff` on the 2 files and here's where the corruption begins: http://i.imgur.com/gqTKW.png ... and the way its corrupt rules out my only idea. Might be a bug in memcache.  I've never used it myself, I can suggest trying Redis or updating your Memcache if there's a new version. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: I think there is a bug in the https://github.com/elbart/node-memcache library you are using.  I reviewed the code and although I could not spot the issue, I can say that it is working with node Buffers as if they are strings, which does not bode well for its ability to handle non-ascii data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elbart's node-memcache does not handle binary values correctly for the reasons Steve Campbell suggests: node-memcache does not give the client direct access to the buffer. By stringifying the buffers, binary data is corrupted.

Use the 'mc' npm. ( npm install mc )

Caveat: I'm the author of the 'mc' npm. I wrote it specifically to handle binary values over memcache's text protocol.

Comment: Thanks. As a temporary solution to my memcache issue, I used a `var cache = {}` as my cache. I started storing objects in a local variable in javascript. It works perfect so far when storing ~250MB of data and 4k objects. My question: what is wrong with doing this? I don't need to access the objects anywhere else; and I won't/shouldn't hit too much memory usage by caching what I need.